# Develop NFT marketplace. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘length’)’

Tags: javascript, nft, error

I have this error ("Upload Failed : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘length’)’") when I try to list my NFT in the market place, I think the error is in the listNFT but I don't know how to solve it. this is the code

```
async function listNFT(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    try{
        const metadataURL = await uploadMetadataToIPFS();
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();

        updateMessage("Please wait (uploading up to 5 minutes)");

        let contract = new ethers.Contract(Marketplace.address, Marketplace.abi, signer);

        const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formParams.price, 'ether');
        let listingPrice = await contract.ottieni_prezzoVendita();
        listingPrice = listingPrice.toString();

        let transaction = await contract.creaOggetto(metadataURL, price, {value: listingPrice});
        await transaction.wait();

        alert("NFT created");
        updateMessage("");
        updateFormParams({name:'',description:'',price:''});
        window.location.replace("/");
    }
    catch(e){
        alert("Upload failed: "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling the listNFT function? it looks okay for me :/

Comment: I call the function in sellNFT.js, I try to debug in vscode but I have some error